# Appllo GraphQL returns null for third level childs

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

GraphQL returns null when access the thrid Level child in Server. When I push static data to client side, it works but when I returns dynamic data it returns null.

When I run it on Local it's worked, ( with local DB connection )  but the same code in server is not working.

**Stack Versions:**
Node Version: 10
NPM versions:
"apollo-server": "^2.3.2",
"apollo-server-express": "^2.3.2", 
"graphql": "^14.1.1",

**Below is fetchSingleHomepage function (Backend code)**

```
exports.fetchSingleHomepage = async function (context) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let query = { isDefault: true }
        if (context && context.city) { query = { city: context.city } }
        Homepages.findOne(query, async (err, homepage) => {
            if (err) { resolve(); }
            else if (homepage) {
                homepage.city.name = (context && context.language && context.language == 'en') ? homepage.city.name_en : homepage.city.name_ar;
                homepage.city.country.name = (context && context.language && context.language == 'en') ? homepage.city.country.name_en : homepage.city.country.name_ar;
                let banners = [];
                let newSections = [];
                homepage.sections = await homepage.sections.map(async (section) => {
                    section.title = (context && context.language && context.language == 'en') ? section.title_en : section.title_ar;
                    section.image = (context && context.language && context.language == 'en') ? (Helpers.getOptimizationImageURl(section.image_en.Location)) : (Helpers.getOptimizationImageURl(section.image_ar.Location));
                    section.image_en = Helpers.getOptimizationImageURl(section.image_en.Location);
                    section.image_ar = Helpers.getOptimizationImageURl(section.image_ar.Location);
                    section.image_sizes = await Helpers.getImageSizes(section.image);
                    if (section.products && section.products.length) {
                        section.products = section.products.map(async (product) => {


                            return await Helpers.formatProduct(product, context.language).then((response) => { return response; });


                        })
                    }
                    if (section.category) {
                        section.category.name = (context && context.language && context.language == 'en') ? section.category.name_en : section.category.name_ar;
                        if (typeof section.category.image == 'object') { section.category.image = Helpers.getOptimizationImageURl(section.category.image.Location); }
                        else if (typeof section.category.image == 'string') { section.category.image = Helpers.getOptimizationImageURl(section.category.image) }
                        else { section.category.image = ''; }
                        section.category.image_sizes = await Helpers.getImageSizes(section.category.image);
                    }

                    if (section.event) {
                        section.event.name = (context && context.language && context.language == 'en') ? section.event.name_en : section.event.name_ar;
                        if (section.event.coverImage && typeof section.event.coverImage == 'object') { section.event.coverImage = section.event.coverImage.Location; }
                        else if (!section.event.image) { section.event.image = ''; }
                        section.event.image_sizes = await Helpers.getImageSizes(section.event.image); 
                        section.event.coverImage_sizes = await Helpers.getImageSizes(section.event.coverImage); 
                    }

                    return section;
                })
                homepage.sections.forEach((section) => {
                    if (section.isBanner) { banners.push(section); }
                    else if (section.isSection) { newSections.push(section); }
                })
                homepage.sections = newSections;
                homepage.banners = banners;
                resolve(homepage);
            }
            else { resolve(); }
        }).populate({
            path: 'city',
            populate: {
                path: 'country'
            }
        }).populate({
            path: 'sections',
            options: { sort: { weight: 1 } },
            populate: [{
                path: 'category',
            },
            {
                path: 'event',
            },
            {
                path: 'products',
                populate: [{
                    path: 'category_id'
                },
                {
                    path: 'modifier'
                },
                {
                    path: 'city_id',
                    populate: {
                        path: 'country'
                    }
                },
                {
                    path: 'supplier'
                },
                {
                    path: 'brand'
                }]
            }]
        }).exec();
    })
}
```

**Below is the formatProduct helper function**

```
exports.formatProduct = function (product, language) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        product.name = language === 'en' ? product.name_en : product.name_ar;
        product.description = language === 'en' ? product.description_en : product.description_ar;
        product.defaultImage = this.getOptimizationImageURl(product.defaultImage);
        if (product.images && product.images.length) {
            product.images = product.images.map((image) => {
                let productImage = ''
                if (image && typeof image === 'object') { productImage = image.Location }
                else if (image && typeof image === 'string') { productImage = image }
                if (productImage) {
                    productImage = this.getOptimizationImageURl(productImage);
                }
                return productImage;
            });
        }

        if (product.defaultImage && product.images && product.images.length) {
            product.images.forEach((image) => {
                if (image === product.defaultImage) {
                    let index = product.images.indexOf(product.defaultImage);
                    if (index > -1) { product.images.splice(index, 1); }
                    product.images.push(product.defaultImage);
                }
            })
        }

        product.images_sizes = await this.getImagesSizes(product.images);
        product.defaultImage_sizes = await this.getImageSizes(product.defaultImage);

        if (product.category_id && product.category_id.length) {
            product.category_id = product.category_id.map(async (category) => {
                category.name = language === 'en' ? category.name_en : category.name_ar;
                if (category.image && typeof category.image === 'object') {
                    category.image = category.image.Location;
                }
                else if (!category.image) {
                    category.image = '';
                }
                category.image_sizes = await this.getImageSizes(category.image);
                return category
            })
        }
        if (product.city_id && product.city_id.length) {
            product.city_id = product.city_id.map((city) => {
                city.name = language === 'en' ? city.name_en : city.name_ar;
                city.country.name = language === 'en' ? city.country.name_en : city.country.name_ar;
                return city;
            })
        }
        product.quantity = 0;
        if (product.modifier && product.modifier.length) {
            product.modifier = product.modifier.filter(modifier => modifier.isActive === true).map(async (modifier) => {
                if (modifier.isDefault) {
                    product.price = (modifier.isDiscount && modifier.discount > 0) ? modifier.price - modifier.discount : modifier.price;
                    product.isDiscounted = modifier.isDiscount;
                    product.discount = modifier.isDiscount ? modifier.discount : 0;
                }
                modifier.size = language === 'en' ? modifier.size_en : modifier.size_ar;
                modifier.out_of_stock = modifier.quantity > 0 ? false : true;
                product.quantity = product.quantity + modifier.quantity;
                if (modifier.image && typeof modifier.image === 'object') { modifier.image = modifier.image.Location; }
                else if (modifier.image && typeof modifier.image === 'string') { modifier.image = modifier.image }
                else { modifier.image = '' }
                modifier.image_sizes = await this.getImageSizes(modifier.image);
                return modifier
            })
        }
        product.out_of_stock = product.quantity > 0 ? false : true;
        if (product.product_id && product.product_id.length) {
            product.product_id = product.product_id.map((childProduct) => {
                childProduct.name = language === 'en' ? childProduct.name_en : childProduct.name_ar;
                childProduct.description = language === 'en' ? childProduct.description_en : childProduct.description_ar;
                if (childProduct.images && childProduct.images.length) {
                    childProduct.images = childProduct.images.map((image) => {
                        if (image && typeof image === 'object') { return image.Location }
                        else if (image && typeof image === 'string') { return image }
                        else { return '' }
                    });
                }
                return childProduct;
            })
        }
        if (product.brand) {
            product.brand.name = language === 'en' ? product.brand.name_en : product.brand.name_ar;
            product.brand.description = language === 'en' ? product.brand.description_en : product.brand.description_ar;

            if (product.brand.image) {
                if (typeof product.brand.image === 'object') { product.brand.image = product.brand.image.Location; }
                else if (typeof product.brand.image === 'string') { product.brand.image = product.brand.image; }
                else { product.brand.image = ''; }

                product.brand.image_sizes = await this.getImageSizes(product.brand.image);
            }
        }

        resolve(product);
    })
}
```

**Graphql Query request**

```
{
  fetchSingleHomepage {
    sections {
      products {
        id
        images_sizes {
          large
        }
        defaultImage_sizes {
          small
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Current response**

```
{
  "data": {
    "fetchSingleHomepage": {
      "sections": [
        {
          "products": [
            {
              "id": "5cdaa658292a2c001819167c",
              "name": "شوكولا كارميه",
              "name_en": "Choco-Carmey",
              "images_sizes": null,
              "defaultImage_sizes": null
            },
            {
              "id": "5cc960eedc1d46001804a648",
              "name": "اسوارة بوليس",
              "name_en": "bracelet- Police ",
              "images_sizes": null,
              "defaultImage_sizes": null
            },
            {
              "id": "5ccb48a9a00f3a00181b60bc",
              "name": "جبر خاطر ",
              "name_en": "pureness",
              "images_sizes": null,
              "defaultImage_sizes": null
            },
```

(In above the images_sizes and defaultImage_sizes are null that is not expected)

**The below is the expected successfull result.**

```
{
  "data": {
    "fetchSingleHomepage": {
      "sections": [
        {
          "products": [
            {
              "id": "5cdaa658292a2c001819167c",
              "images_sizes": [
                {
                  "large": "http://dev-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Products/5cdaa658292a2c001819167c/LARGE/L1557833304916"
                },
                {
                  "large": "http://dev-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Products/5cdaa658292a2c001819167c/LARGE/L1557833304918"
                },
                {
                  "large": "http://dev-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Products/5cdaa658292a2c001819167c/LARGE/L1557833304913"
                }
              ],
              "defaultImage_sizes": {
                "small": "http://dev-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/Products/5cdaa658292a2c001819167c/SMALL/S1557833304913"
              }
            },
```

Comment: `return await Helpers.formatProduct(product, context.language).then((response) => { return response; });`

This will retunr the product object, and the sub objects are coming from it.

Comment: Ah. So maybe include the code for `Helpers.formatProduct`?

Comment: Yes, Updated the `formatProduct` in code